# Configuration issue for web app on iis express

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, app-config

I have a problem  in connecting local DB in my web app to run it on iis express.
I developed the application on VS2017 (my os is win10) and to run it on iis I installed sql server 2017 express (until now every thing is ok).
I tested the aap on 2 lap tops have win10 and it is working fine(I installed sqlserver2017exp).
Main pc that I want to run the application on it has win7(not mine) does not supports sqlserver2017exp or 2016 so I installed 2014 but it does not work.
I re-created db by sqlserver2014 and copied it to app_datafolder but I still have same error.

I have lap top has win7 I installed vs2015 to redevelop the application (opened old one and copies code to new one)when I run application by vs2015 I got same error.
I modified web.config many times but I did get correct solution until now.

I need to run application on win7

Error message:
"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\ITTIHAD FC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MCL\App_Data\MCL.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

Thank you

```
<configuration>
```

```
<system.web>
  <globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>

  <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="">

    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Default.aspx"/>

  </customErrors>

  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>

  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />

  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages></system.web>
```

Comment: Sounds like the error is telling you the problem; the database already exists or you don't have access to said file. *Don't forget, Windows 7 is completely out of support in only a couple months, so trying to "downgrade" your app to work on old (and to be completely unsupported) environments may be more work they actually getting the upgrades done.*

Comment: Could it be that the code is trying to attach to a database file when there is a named database instance with the same name?

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you for responding. As I mentioned, I redeveloped application by VS2015 on win 7 & I still has same problem. And for DB name e I do not have any file n computer has same name. Do you suggest to use older version of VS? Please check web.config file as I mentioned in my question. By the way I know win7 will be out of support in 2020 but user has this computer.